# How to save generated pdf in server using dompdf php lib

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using dompdf php lib for generating pdf.

Right now it ask user to save the file in their machine.

**Code i tried so far:**

```
<?php
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename.'.pdf');
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($filename.'.pdf', $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give "write" permission to the directory you need to put the file.